# Move Document using Drop Off Library

Tags: document-library, document, drop-off-library

I have a document library named **"MyDocLibrary"** and in that i have define content type.
same content type define in Drop Off Library.
also set Content Organizer Setting and Rules for when document is upload in Drop Off Library then it automatically move to **MyDocLibrary**

**Document moved successfully but getting this screen,**
Look this image.
[image]

i checked fields but no any field is read only.
i don't know how occur this screen..

How to resolve these issue ?

Thanks...

Comment: Is your content type containing a custom user field?

Comment: no any custom field in my content type

Comment: OK, so at least then it's not the beloved 'g' error (http://www.spdoctor.net/Pages/message.aspx?name=fatalerror-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-g) :)